# Cannot click bluetooth button after toggling it a few times

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth, 20.04, kde

I am stumbling upon this glitch from some time and it does not stop, I hoped it to end after an update or a restart but non of them worked. A restart is a temporary fix for this though, but it continues to happen if I replicate the steps again.

The problem is: I cannot click on this button below after I toggle it a few times.

[image: bluetooth button]

I have tried relating this to some questions asked on the web but it seems to be a rare issue, or might just be me.

This issue comes up if I toggle the button a few times with a small minute of gap.

I try to do these things after I come across this bug:

- Restart my computer (logging out and back in does not work) (Fixes it temporarily)
- Try to update
- Click on the button straight to the right side of the button (The screenshot tool makes the widget go away, I'm sorry I cannot take a picture of it). It shows me 'your bluetooth needs to be fixed' or something like that, when I click on it, it does nothing